# Can I reorder a fetched entity with a date attribute for a UITableView after it was fetched from CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have an Entity in coredata that I fetch. I pass this Entity around to other View Controllers, one of those ViewControllers has a UITableView that I would like to display based on the Date attribute (part of the Entity I am passing around) from newest to oldest. I'm just not sure how to re-organize that data so that the date Attributes are in chronological order after the Entity has already been fetched.

Update

This is what I tried to add

CurrentStatment is my Entity, and I access another set of Entities through it called History. History has an attribute called date, which is the value I'm trying to compare.

```
// sort date array
    historyArray = currentStatement?.history?.array as! [History]

    historyArray.sorted(by:{$0.date!.compare($1.date as! Date) == .orderedAscending})
```

But I am getting a warning: Result to call to 'sorted(by) is unused

Answer (score 2):

You can sort an array using `myArray.sorted(by: ...)`

So, in your case, to sort the dates newest-to-oldest, use: `let sortedEntities = myEntityArray.sorted(by: {$0.Date.compare($1.Date) == .orderAscending})`

More on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/2296242-sorted

Comment: I tried to add what you suggested, but seems to be giving me a warning, I updated the question so you can see.

Comment: Updated answer to fix warning

Comment: The warning was telling you that the function returned a value, and you never cast that value to a variable.